# Finding longest string in numerical order in a string in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I have a string with thousands of number in it. I need to go through the string and find the longest set of characters that are in numerical order. For example:

```
string = '1223123341223455'
```

The longest string of characters in that string in numerical order is 1223455 and it is 7 characters long. Here is an example of what I have at the moment:

```
r=r2=''
a=b=0
 while a < len(string)+1:
    if string[a] <= string[b]:
        r += string[a]
    else:
        if len(r) < len(r2):
            r = r2
    a += 1
    b += 1
```

With this it tells me that the string index is out of range on the line:

```
if string[a] <= string[b]
```

Here is my logic: Check to see if the first number is less than or equal to the second number. If it is, those two numbers are in numerical order. Add that first number to an empty string. Keep doing this until you run into a point when the first number is greater than the second number. After this point is reached, save what you have as a string and continue where you left off, except this time concatenate the number you accumulate to a different string. After you have two strings of numbers, compare the two and take the higher one. Continue this until you are done processing the string. I hope this makes sense, kind of hard to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings are indexed at 0. So if you try to access `some_str[len(some_str)]` you will get an `IndexError` because the highest index of that string is `len(some_str) - 1`. Change your `while` condition to: `while a < len(myString):`. Also, you shouldn't use `string` as a variable, as it may overshadow the python `string` module name.

Comment: The `string` module is rarely used these days, and, anyway, having a variable of that name won't stop you from importing from the module. Shadowing is only a problem when you do it to a built-in name such as `str`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are incrementing `a` one too many times. Therefore, the program breaks when a equals the length of the string (`a = 16`). Changing your 3rd line to `while a < len(string):` should fix it.

Also, I'm not quite sure what you're doing with your variables. You declare r1, which is never used, and you use r2 without declaring it. The problem can be solved more easily than your method - the following code seems to do what you want:

```
>>> r=longest=''
>>> for a in range(1:len(string)):
        if (string[a-1] <= string[a]) or len(r)==0:
            r += string[a]
        else:
        r = string[a]       // We need to reset r if the string is not in numerical order
        if len(r) > len(longest):
            longest = r
        a += 1
>>> longest
'1223455'
```

Comment: He is not only iterating too many times... He is also comparing the same number :)

a=0 and b=0 and both are incremented at the end.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have several things to test and the expected results, including boundary cases.

```
strings = {
    '1223123341223455': '1223455',  # at the end
    '1': '1',                       # just one
    '12321': '123',                 # at the start
    '212321': '123',                # in the middle
    '': '',                         # empty
    '123234': '123',                # two of same length, take the first
    '12231233412234552': '1223455', # at the end -1 testing the try
```

}

Then search for the longest string *without* appending the actual characters found so far to some temporary string. That is inefficient. You only need to know the start index of the longest string and its length:

```
def longest(s):
    max_start = 0
    this_start = 0
    max_length_minus_one = 0
    for x in range(len(s)-1):
        if s[x] > s[x+1]:
            length_found = x - this_start
            if length_found > max_length_minus_one:
                max_length_minus_one = length_found
                max_start = this_start
            this_start = x + 1
    try:
        # test the final string position
        length_found = x + 1 - this_start
        if length_found > max_length_minus_one:
            max_length_minus_one = length_found
            max_start = this_start
    except UnboundLocalError:
        pass # empty string throws this exception
    return s[max_start:max_start+max_length_minus_one+1]
```

Now run this on the test cases and check the output:

```
for s, check in strings.iteritems():
    res = longest(s)
    print repr(s), repr(res), 'OK' if res == check else '<<<<< ERROR'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = '1223123341223455'

longest = ''
r = ''

for i in range(len(string)):
    j = i+1
    r += string[i]

    if j > len(string)-1 or string[i] > string[j]:
        if len(r) > len(longest):
            longest = r
            r = ''


print longest # 1223455
```